# Displaying functions, objects & arrays on a chrome browser

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

We have used both Notepad++ and Brackets.io, and have the same issue with both.

We can display a variable like the code below:

```
var storedVariable = 2+2;
alert(storedVaribale);
```

When we try to display a function or object the page is blank:

```
 function Andrewsfuntion (x=0,x<100,x++){
 document.write(x);
 }

 beer = {
 Name: "Heineken",
 Country: "Australia",
 Price: 7.50
 }
```

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title> Scrath Pad </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scratchpad.js"></script>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
</head>

<body>
<div container = class> 
<p> I don't know how to code </p>
</div>
<script> 


function Andrewsfuntion (x=0,x<100,x++){
document.write(x);
}

var x;
Andrewsfuntion();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function Andrewsfuntion (x=0,x<100,x++){` simply is a syntax error. You should get an error in the browser's devtools console. It looks like you're mixing a function declaration with a loop header. Notice this has nothing to do with the editor you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Functions and Loops

From your code, it is not particularly clear what you are trying to do.

A **function** is simply a wrapper for code, so that you can use it multiple times.

What you seem to be trying to write, however, is a **for loop** (that is, a block of code that repeats some actions numerous times). If you want to make a loop that prints out the numbers from 0 to 100, you can do it like this:

```js
for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  document.write(i);
 }
```

(you'd probably want to add line breaks or some other kind of delimiter so that the numbers are all seperate).

However, a function would look like this:

```js
function AndrewsFunction() {
  document.write("hello, world!");
}

AndrewsFunction();
```

There, you have just wrapped up other code and then called it to run it, whereas in the for loop, you have wrapped up other code and `i` number of times.

---

### Displaying Object Fields

With regards to displaying information from an object, you would have to simply specify what information you want to display from the object, for example:

```js
 function AndrewsFunction () {
   document.write(beer.Name);
 }

 beer = {
 Name: "Heineken",
 Country: "Australia",
 Price: 7.50
 }
 
 AndrewsFunction();
```

There, you can see we are getting the `Name` field from the `beer` object, and then printing it to the page.

---

### Next Steps

I would recommend that you take a look at a Javascript book or online tutorial. Some that come to mind:

- https://www.codecademy.com/
- http://www.learn-js.org/
- Head First Javascript (book)

A quick Google search should come up with a lot more.

Comment: I'm sorry to disagree, but we really shouldn't be encouraging people to use `document.write()` for debugging. It is very much the wrong tool for the job. Learning to use the browser's developer tools will be much more productive.

Comment: I agree 100% with that, which is why I recommended that they look at some Javascript tutorials at the end of my post. There was just so much to cover to fix their problem that I didn't really want to get into it too in depth into why they shouldn't be using that function

Comment: Very true! Well, between the two of us we've hopefully given the OP some good areas to explore.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to learn here is how to debug JavaScript code. It's good that you are trying out different things like `alert()` and `document.write()`. But those are not really good ways to debug your code.

`document.write()` is particularly troublesome. Unless you call directly from a `<script>` tag *while the page is loading*, it will *erase* the page before writing the new content. `alert()` is also problematic and not ideal for debugging.

Every browser has a JavaScript debugger built into it. This is what you should use to debug your code. You can use `console.log()` to log a value to the JavaScript console, or even better, add a `debugger;` statement in your code at the place where you would like to look at things. Then if you load your page with the developer tools open, it will stop at that `debugger;` statement, and you can look at all your variables, and you can step through your code statement by statement to see what it does.

Here is a great [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). I recommend going through this document and trying out all the things it talks about. (There is also a link near the top of the doc to a newer version; I like this old version myself, but I recommend reading both.)

The developer tools will also give you error messages when your syntax is wrong. Take your example:

```
function Andrewsfuntion (x=0,x<100,x++) { /* ... */ }
```

If you have the developer tools open when you try to run this, you will see that it has a syntax error that prevents the code from running at all:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Granted, this message doesn't quite tell you *exactly* what is wrong, but at least it will point you toward the line with the problem. And it sure beats staring at a blank page wondering why nothing happened.

By getting familiar with the developer tools, you will have a much easier time debugging your code.

In addition, I agree wholeheartedly with Toastrackenigma's suggestion to go through some basic JavaScript tutorials to learn the syntax of the language. But when your code doesn't work, don't guess why: use the developer tools to help you find where you went wrong.